# Где взять LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "icmp.lib"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компиляция, библиотеки, компоновщик

Скачал исходники программы на C++. Довольно старая, написана, на сколько я понял, в Visual Studio Express 2008 (возможно ещё в более старшей версии). Пытаюсь скомпилировать её на Visual Studio Community 2017.

В readme указано следующее:

> You need:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio (e.g. VS .NET 7.1)
>
> Libraries:
>
> - OpenSSL
> - zlib
> - libjpeg
>
> compile each as static library, then add libs/headers to compiler
>   paths
>
> also add Microsoft's IPHLPAPI import library to compiler paths
>   (usually comes with Microsoft Visual Studio).

Я в английском не силён, но вышеуказанные библиотеки все подключил и MFC установил (тоже необходимо было). Google выдаёт по запросу "LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "icmp.lib"", всего одну страницу.

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, буду очень благодарен. Спасибо!

Comment: icmp.lib нет в современных версиях Windows SDK. Функции из него, по видимому, переехали в IPHlpApi.Lib

Comment: Подождите, гугл даёт что нету  "icmp.lib", или студия даёт что нету "icmp.lib"? Гугл не может знать что "icmp.lib" не хватает студии. Напишите нормально текст ошибки. Начиная с шифра и заканчивая точкой.

Comment: @nick_n_a Но ведь текст ошибки приведен в заголовке... Очевидно его дает компоновщик студии, а не гугл.

Comment: Как можно задействовать IPHlpApi.Lib?

Comment: Например, `#pragma comment(lib, "IPHlpApi.Lib")`

Comment: Если посредством  #pragma подключена библиотека, прийдется или утилитой `lib` или `tlib icmp.lib` создать библиотеку. Можно попробовать скачать её в интенете.

Comment: Я бы скачал, но где скачать, не могу найти.

Comment: что именно? icmp.lib - в Windows SDK версии, примерно соответствующей Windows 98. IPHlpApi.Lib - в любой современной версии SDK